# angular.element replaceWith not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an element to replace and the html text is in varaiable `h`
The first call to this works perfectly. But the second call does not.

```
var newElement;
var h="<div>a</div>";
newElement = angular.element(h);
$compile(newElement[0])($scope);        
angular.element($element[0]).replaceWith(newElement[0]);
```

Comment: What is it? You see any kind of error in browser console. If yes, please post it.

Comment: NO ERRORS.. JUST THAT NEXT TIME IT IS NOT REPLACING THE ELEMENT

Comment: i even tried debugging the code ..

Comment: create a `jsfiddle` and post it. Then only you can get answer here. It's like shooting the target in dark.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake here is you have compiled the html template but u havent used it .

```
var newElement;
var h="<div>a</div>";
newElement = angular.element(h);

angular.element($element[0]).replaceWith($compile(newElement[0])($scope));
```

Hope this solution works