# replaceWith not working in custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I know this is a previously asked question, but just once in the angular context (with the same title), many more for jQuery.... No answers though for the angular question, people asked for a fiddle/plunker reproducing the problem, which is legit.

So, I re-ask the question as I couldn't comment in the [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156903/angular-element-replacewith-not-working) and provide [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IcuFoH98Ckck8wcOSSKt?p=preview).

Directives are located in `app.js` file (only directives there), the `localtest.js` file is the jasmine test of interest. You can see the error just when you load the the plunker. There are console.log calls, so you can open firebug/devtools to check that, after having called `element.replaceWith()` the element object is the same than before.

**Am I (and the other guy) doing something wrong?** (which I suspect, but I don't know what :-S)

Comment: You should also include relevant code to the question. I found [this angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8710). There might be other/older ones.

Comment: It seems to be specific to jasmine though, as the testing directive is working when you use it in an angular app off jasmine tests. When debugging `elem.replaceWith(replacement);`, `elem` is not replaced with replacement after that line, but in an angular app `elem` contains the new replacement markup...